# Read the data inserted of a first executed stored procedure in a second stored procedure without commiting?

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have a java my business like this:
1-Call Stored procedure SP_INSERTS: Insert data without commiting
2-Call a web service: retrive data to the call of the next step.
3-Call Stored Procedure SP_UPDATES: Update the data created in the first step.
4-Commit or rollback if everything is OK or not OK.

The problem i'm having is that in the third step, the stored procedure is not finding the data inserted in the first step(no data found), only if I commit aftert the second step I can find the data. Do you know what could I do? Any hints?

Comment: It should already work, as long as #1 and #3 are in the same database transaction, i.e. using the same database connection, so why would that not be the case? From the way you described it, #2 is a web service call to *retrieve* some data, so #3 should be back in the same app that did #1.

Comment: Thanks for try to answer. The issue is that we are managing that. If we commit after the 1st or 2nd step, the 3rd ends ok because it finds the data. But I don't want to commit in that steps, I have to do it in the 4th mandatory.

Comment: see example https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

Comment: A read of data will always see inserts/updates/deletes previously done in the *same* database transaction, so if step 3 doesn't see the data from step 1, **then it is not in the same database transaction**. If you think it is, then think again, because what you describe can only happen if step 3 is done by code using a different database transaction.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, that kind of answer I'm try to find, because I think the same and surely something is going wrong. Could be possible to have two connections at the same time? Because if I commit the first Stored procedure from Java is the only way that the second call can complete as I want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Java guy, but as long as all this is done in the same transaction, you should be good. I think by default, the JDBC drive is in auto commit mode, so each statement commits once it's done. You can change this behavior with:

```
con.setAutoCommit(false);
```

This requires all these steps be done by the same connection, so if you're using some sort of connection pooling, this probably won't work.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html#disable_auto_commit

Comment: OP is complaining that things don't work right if they *don't* commit the changes, so obviously OP already knows how to prevent auto-commit.